# BroadcastReceiver - como registrar para o método addProximityAlert

Tags: java, android

O *snippet* abaixo tem a missão de dar um aviso ao usuário se ele entrou numa área de terreno que é um círculo em torno das coordenadas geográficas dadas:

```
double mLatitude=35.41;
double mLongitude=139.46;

float mRadius=500f;

long expiration=-1;

Intent mIntent = new Intent ("Você entrou na área demarcada");

PendingIntent mFireIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadCast(this,-1,mIntent,0);

mLocationManager.addProximityAlert(mLatitude, mLongitude, mRadius, expiration, mFireIntent);
```

não funcionará de per si naturalmente porque está incompleto. Falta instanciar `LocationManager` e também registrar o `BroadcastReceiver` que, pelo que entendi, funciona quase como um *listener*.

Falta ainda dizer o `IntentFilter` associado a alguma ação. E é este o meu problema.

Como registrar o BroadcastReceiver para a ação requerida, que é a disparada pelo método `addProximityAlert`?

Não encontrei algo similar a, por exemplo,

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON);
intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
registerReceiver(intentReceiver, intentFilter);
```

que vigiaria o clique no botão de uma câmera.

(Este objeto `intentReceiver` acima - no registro do *receiver* - é a instanciação num outro ponto do código de uma classe particular que estendeu `BroadcastReceiver`, cujo método único `onReceive` iria filtrar se haveria o tal clique no botão da câmera)

Ali, no `IntentFilter` paralelo ao meu problema, a ação vigiada é o clique na câmera.

Como fazer um semelhante, de modo a registrar a efetiva resposta do método `addProximityAlert`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao criar o IntentFilter você define a ação que pretende. Ela não é mais do que uma String.

Você apenas tem de garantir que essa String é unica. Normalmente utiliza-se o nome da package mais algo que identifique a ação.

Por exemplo: nomePackage.ProximityAlert

O IntentFilter seria então instanciado assim:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("nomePackage.ProximityAlert");
```

Não esquecer que o `Intent` deverá ser criado também com esse `IntentFilter`:

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent ("nomePackage.ProximityAlert");

PendingIntent mFireIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadCast(this,-1,mIntent,0);

mLocationManager.addProximityAlert(mLatitude, mLongitude, mRadius, expiration, mFireIntent);
```

Para facilitar é habitual declarar uma valor `static` para guardar a String do filtro:

```
public static final String PROX_ALERT_INTENT = "nomePackage.ProximityAlert";
```

Comment: Caro @ramaral, eu gostaria de dar como encerrada, mas acho que minha 'reputação' ainda não permite. Melhor, nem saberia como fazê-lo pelos mecanismos do forum. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Você só necessita de clicar no "V" que se encontra no lado esquerdo da resposta, junto ao número zero. Veja [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: me esqueci de comentar. E aquela linha que define a ação a ser 'vigiada', que diz intentFilter.addAction, para efeitos de uso no onReceive do BroadcastReceiver não é necessária?

Comment: Neste caso não. No construtor você já está a indicar a `Action`. Isso só é necessário se você quiser que o `Intent` responda a mais do que uma ação. A documentação do Android explica detalhadamente como isso funciona: [link1](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html), [link2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)